# Чи є нормативним вживання слова "сторчак" у значенні "перпендикуляр"?

Tags: вибір-слова

Коли навчалась в школі, вчителі говорили деякі знайомі терміни незвичними словами:

> ***[Перпендикуляр](http://sum.in.ua/s/perpendykuljar)*** - Пряма, що перетинає дану пряму або площину під прямим кутом;  називали ***[Сторчак](http://sum.in.ua/s/storchak)*** - Те, що стирчить, різко видається вперед або вгору.

(Визначення взяті з Словника української мови: в 11 томах.)

Підтвердження правильності заміни одного слова іншим не знайшла.
***Чи є дані терміни нормативними?***

Comment: здається ви знайшли помилки в СУМ, бо цей вираз трохи не зрозумілий *Прима, що перетинав*

Comment: @Yola, там у них багато помилок. Я їм ще на пошту колись писав, мовляв, як краще повідомляти: натискати «це помилка», робити коментар чи писати поштою. Хоча здебільшого там помилки в наголосах (відсутній наголос, що є в паперовій версії або стоїть не там, де в паперовій). На [ukrlit](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/перпендикуляр) конкретно цієї помилки немає. Зате там і паперову версію дивитися не дають.